# Copy a txt file with today date as file name

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have a `abc.txt` file. I would like to create a batch file to copy `abc.txt` file with today date as file name. The file name like `20150821good.txt`

How can I change the following code:

```
copy *.txt 20150821good.txt
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96380/how-to-append-date-to-backup-file take a look at this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the first 8 characters of `wmic os get localdatetime` to get today's date.  Capture it with `for /f`.  Example:

```js
@echo off
setlocal

for /f %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /value ^| find "="') do set "%%I"
set "today=%localdatetime:~0,8%"

if not exist "combined\" md combined
rem // remove "echo" when you're confident this does what you intend
echo copy *.txt "combined\%today%good.txt"
```